# What java framework is easiest to use with embedded Jetty web server?

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, jetty, seam, embedded-jetty

I want to create java application with embedded web server (Jetty, are there any other servers which I can use for that?) and database (H2). GUI of application will be accessible through web browser. 
I can choose any framework which will allow me to create RCP application easy and work flawlessly witch my server. Also good behavior of hot swapping is important. Is JRebel needed at all with embedded Jetty?
I think it's mostly the battle between Seam 3 and Spring 3, but maybe someone have any real experience with that kind of setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jetty is probably the easiest web server to embed. If you are looking for a very small, lightweight configuration, consider creating your own `main()` method that builds a Jetty `Server` programatically.

For development, you can also use the `org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner` interface to create a class that watches the paths you want and restarts the webapp when files change. For running from the console, I also created a Thread that periodically scans stdin so that when I hit Enter, the web app reloads.

I can't speak to Seam, but with Spring, the whole server starts up in about 5 seconds. Webapp reloads take less than 2 seconds. This may be fast enough that you don't need someting like JRebel.